# matchVisual is not working in React Quill 2.0

Tags: reactjs, quill, react-quill

I am trying to remove the extra `<p><br></p>` tags that are present as line breaks while using React Quill. I tried implementing the `matchVisual` parameter outlined [here](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill/issues/250), but it still seems to be giving me that paragraph and br tags in the output. [Here is a code pen](https://codepen.io/douglasrcjames/pen/zYGvMPd) showing simple changes to the Quill demo setup, and it still doesn't work.

I declare the modules for Quill in the constructor like:

```
 constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { editorHtml: '', theme: 'snow' }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.modules = {
            toolbar: [
                [{ 'header': '1'}, {'header': '2'}],
                [{size: []}],
                ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote'],
                [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}, 
                {'indent': '-1'}, {'indent': '+1'}],
                [{ align: '' }, { align: 'center' }, { align: 'right' }, { align: 'justify' }],
                ['link', 'image'],
                ['clean']
            ],
            clipboard: {
              matchVisual: false,
            }
          }
        
    this.formats = [
      'header', 'size',
      'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote',
      'list', 'bullet', 'indent',
      'link', 'image', 'align'
    ]
  }
```

I am probably doing something just a tad bit wrong; any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **`matchVisual` has been removed as an option**. This change occurred with Quill 2.0, as noted in [the release notes on GitHub](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/ee827ffb605ba491246f201d497ce0e7d9e193a0/docs/guides/upgrading-to-2-0.md#configuration).